# How to calculate Kinetic energy and potential energy of a Ball?

Tags: python, pymunk

I want to calculate the Kinetic energy and potential energy of the ball I just Spawned inside a Pymunk space.

I wanted to replicate [this](https://phet.colorado.edu/sims/html/energy-skate-park-basics/latest/energy-skate-park-basics_en.html).

Where the values change in real-time along with the graph. from what I saw in the documentation these are the things we can get from the body:

```
Kinetic energy  
velocity 
mass
```

but some of them are in vec2d object idk how that works.

Comment: So you already have the kinetic energy and your question is how to calculate the potential energy?

Comment: yes you are right

Comment: You need to multiply the height of the object with its mass and the gravitational acceleration. What programming problem do you have related to that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To determine `kinetic energy` you will need an objects `mass` and the `magnitute of its velocity`, then calculate

`kinetic energy = 0.5 * mass * (magnitute of velocity)**2`.

For potential energy, you will need the objects `mass`, the magnitute of `gravity` (the contstant downwards acceleration) of your space, and the objects `height` relative to an arbitrary (up to your choice) horizontal zero level. Then calculate

`potential energy = mass * magnitude of gravity * relative height`.

To keep the measurings consistent, you must use the same units of measurements in each calculation. Sticking with SI unit is probably the wisest, so kilograms `kg` for `mass`, meters per second `m/s` for magnitudes of `velocity`, meters per second squared `m/(s**2)` for `gravity` and meters (m) for `height`. Then the resulting energies are in both Joules `J = kg*(m* *2)/(s**2)`.